# on('change',myfunc ) is not working on angular.elememt query selector

Tags: angularjs, ng-img-crop

I am using ngImgCrop to crop my selected image.....for selecting image i am using input type file and applying an on-change event on that input using

`angular.element(document.querySelector('#fileInput'))`

this is working great and giving expected output in my plunker...now I am trying to implement this in my project...unfortunately its not working.....means I am able to select the file but that onchange method is not triggering

[HERE](https://plnkr.co/edit/64DOPvYgjX1iuCQJZlT4?p=preview) is my plunker and waiting for some help

please don't suggest me for a directive I want it should be within controller only

**update**
That image selecting and showing html is placed inside a meterial dialog like below....

```
<md-dialog aria-label="User Settings" flex flex-gt-sm="70" flex-gt-md="60"
        class="userSettingsModal">

    <md-dialog-content>
        <md-tabs md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-selected="userVm.selectedTab">
            //my first tab
             //second
            //third tab

             <!-- Profile Image -->
             <md-tab label="Profile Image">
                <md-content class="image-upload">
                    <div class="md-icon-float md-block">
                        <div class="sub-header">Upload User Image</div>
                        <input type="file" id="fileInput" accept="image/*" />
                        <div class="crop-area">
                            <img-crop area-type="square" image="myImage" result-image="myCroppedImage"></img-crop>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-show="myImage">
                            <div id="crop-header">Cropped Image:</div>
                            <div><img ng-src="{{myCroppedImage}}"/></div>
                        </div>
                        <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="myfunction(myCroppedImage)">Upload</md-button>

                    </div>

             </md-tab>
         </md-tabs>
    </md-dialog-content>
</md-dialog>
```

Comment: You need to provide your project code where it is not working rather than providing the plunk which is working.

Comment: @aka the same code  i am using

Comment: So you mean that if i download this plunkr and run it will not work. It works only in plunkr?

Comment: my question is that.....its not working in my project but working in plunker....i mean i am doing the needfull in my project but that function is not calling

Comment: In plunkr it is working fine. I believe there might be some silly mistake that you may have made on your project code. Can you please share your project code?

Comment: That what i am saying to post your code where you are using this and it is not working. Instead of posting the plunkr where it is working

Comment: Side note: You don't need the queryselector when using `angular.element`. You could do the above with only `angular.element('#fileInput')`

Comment: dear responders thanks for your commnents....please see my update above once

Comment: @NikolajDamLarsen please check it my plunker simply nothing happens